# Mimicing Mac-style command/alt/control keys in Linux

Tags: linux, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I absolutely love that Mac separates the command key from the control key, allowing OS shortcuts and text shortcuts to co-exist. It's incredibly useful, especially because it allows emacs shortcuts *everywhere*.

I've searched almost everywhere for some kind of utility that can allow this and can't find anything. Any help?

Note: I want to do more than just remap my keyboard. I want to actually split OS shortcuts and text shortcuts. The only way I can see doing that is to manually go through each shortcut in Gnome and Compiz and change it.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 02/03/2020**

Kinto has now been rewritten in C for Ubuntu/Debian systems using x11. It also uses json config files, making it easier to manage and extend to other applications than just terminals. The app no longer maps to Super in the Terminal apps, it will now properly map to Ctrl+Shift to create the exact same feel as having a Cmd key.

Please checkout the latest release.
https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

The main change to allow for the Super = Ctrl+Shift change is in this symbols file.

```
default partial xkb_symbols "mac_levelssym" {
    key <LWIN> {
      repeat= no,
      type= "ONE_LEVEL",
      symbols[Group1]= [ Hyper_L ],
      actions[group1]=[ SetMods(modifiers=Shift+Control) ]
    };
    key <RWIN> {
      repeat= no,
      type= "ONE_LEVEL",
      symbols[Group1]= [ Hyper_R ],
      actions[group1]=[ SetMods(modifiers=Shift+Control) ]
    };
};
```

---

You may find Kinto to be useful. It's a project I recently created, after a few years of tackling this problem a few different ways and I just now feel like it's solid enough to share.

The Kinto installer simply uses python to do the initial install, after that it's just a systemd service, bash, xprop, setxkbmap and xkbcomp. As far as I am concerned it is the fastest and most native solution to this problem that you are going to find.

https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto

https://medium.com/@benreaves/kinto-a-mac-inspired-keyboard-mapping-for-linux-58f731817c0

Here's a Gist as well, if you just want to see what is at the heart of it all, it will not alternate your keymap when needed though. The Gist also does not include custom xkb keymap files that setup macOS style cursors/word-wise manipulations that use Cmd and the arrow keys.

https://gist.github.com/rbreaves/f4cf8a991eaeea893999964f5e83eebb

gist content

```
# permanent apple keyboard keyswap
echo "options hid_apple swap_opt_cmd=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf
update-initramfs -u -k all

# Temporary & instant apple keyboard keyswap
echo '1' | sudo tee -a /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/swap_opt_cmd

# Windows and Mac keyboards - GUI (Physical Alt is Ctrl, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Super)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win

# Windows and Mac keyboards - Terminal Apps (Physical Alt is Super, Physical Super is Alt, Physical Ctrl is Ctrl)
setxkbmap -option;setxkbmap -option altwin:swap_alt_win

#
# If you want a systemd service and bash script to help toggle between
# GUI and Terminal applications then look at project Kinto.
# https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto
#
# Note: The above may not work for Chromebooks running Linux, please look
# at project Kinto for that.
#
# If anyone would like to contribute to the project then please do!
#
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: If I thought I could have added something substantial to the question asked by tailoring the answer then I would have done so. Overall this is a pretty common question and they all pretty well share the same answer.

Either way I was not aware of the policy to either flag or close duplicate questions. I will keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Anything for Wayland or Gnome?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried this myself but I found this over "Ask Ubuntu":

Install AutoKey:

```
apt-get install autokey-gtk
```

and set a phrase to:

```
Phrase Text: <ctrl>+C (actually type out the <ctrl>+ here)
Paste Using: Keyboard
Abbreviation: None
Hotkey: <super>+v
Window Filter: None
```

See here: [How to make keyboard work like OSX System Wide?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10008/how-to-make-keyboard-work-like-osx-system-wide)